# nginx redirect with regexp

Tags: nginx

I had an old site that was built with ASP, the homepage url looked like this "www.hifimaven.com/index.asp". But now the new site is built on top of RubyOnRails using nginx. and the new url to the homepage "www.hifimaven.com".

How can I tell nginx to redirect to the new homepage url if the user types the old url instead of showing a 404 page.

Answer (score 2):

enclosing rewrite rule into location will make processing faster:

```
location = /index.asp {
       rewrite ^ http://www.hifimaven.com permanent;
}
```

adding rewrite rule globally to server {} will cause nginx to check all request uri to the pattern in the rule. Location, especially with strict comparisong, is much faster and correct from ideological point of view.

Answer (score 0):

im not the best at nginx rewrites but im pretty sure something like this should do

rewrite /index.asp$ http://www.hifimaven.com permanent;

Answer (score 0):

No need to enclose in `location`

```
rewrite ^/index.asp$ http://www.hifimaven.com/ permanent;
```